# opencv2: imwrite Python error with Windows: can't open file for writing: permission denied

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to execute this part of code for splitting an image into 10*10 pieces, but I keep receiving the error message below when writing the images. Can anyone help me?
Also, it happens after writing the first image as 'P1'.

```
num = 1
for i in range (0,rows-11,10):
    for j in range (0,cols-11,10):
       box = img[i:i+10,j:j+10]
       image_label = 'P' + str(num)
       cv2.imwrite(image_label+'.jpg', box)
```

[ WARN:0@26028.025] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (773) cv::imwrite_ imwrite_('P1.jpg'): can't open file for writing: permission denied

Comment: `num` is always `1`? You always try to overwrite the same file.

Comment: What operating system?  What directory are you in?  The error is quite clear -- you don't have permission to write into whatever directory you're in.

Comment: what does `os.getcwd()` return